# I get an error when trying to build a docker Image for my Jhipster 7.1.0 gateway application (webpack error)

Tags: node.js, webpack, jhipster

I just generate an Jhipster gateway application by the `generate-jhipster`

And then when I run `./gradlew bootJar -Pprod jibDockerBuild`

I get an webpack error:

```
[webpack-cli] Failed to load '/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/webpack/webpack.prod.js' config
[webpack-cli] Error: Cannot find module 'workbox-build/build/options/schema/webpack-generate-sw'
Require stack:
- /run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js
- /run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js
- /run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/webpack/webpack.prod.js
- /run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js
- /run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js
- /run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js
- /run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:902:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:746:27)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19)
    at require (/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js:20:33)
    at Module._compile (/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1114:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:950:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:790:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:974:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/generate-sw.js',
    '/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/workbox-webpack-plugin/build/index.js',
    '/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/webpack/webpack.prod.js',
    '/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/webpack-cli.js',
    '/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/webpack-cli/lib/bootstrap.js',
    '/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js',
    '/run/media/witcher/WORKS/study-space-flatform/StudySpace/node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js'
  ]
}
```

I'm sure it appeared in `package.json` `devDependencies`

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@testing-library/react": "11.2.7",
    "@types/jest": "26.0.23",
    "@types/lodash": "4.14.170",
    "@types/node": "15.12.2",
    "@types/react": "17.0.11",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.7",
    "@types/react-redux": "7.1.16",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "5.1.7",
    "@types/redux": "3.6.31",
    "@types/webpack-env": "1.16.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.27.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.27.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.2.6",
    "browser-sync": "2.26.14",
    "browser-sync-webpack-plugin": "2.3.0",
    "concurrently": "6.2.0",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "9.0.0",
    "core-js": "3.14.0",
    "cross-env": "7.0.3",
    "css-loader": "5.2.6",
    "css-minimizer-webpack-plugin": "3.0.1",
    "cypress": "7.5.0",
    "cypress-audit": "1.0.0",
    "eslint": "7.28.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-cypress": "2.11.3",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "7.24.0",
    "eslint-webpack-plugin": "2.5.4",
    "file-loader": "6.2.0",
    "fork-ts-checker-webpack-plugin": "6.2.10",
    "generator-jhipster": "7.1.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "5.3.1",
    "husky": "4.3.8",
    "identity-obj-proxy": "3.0.0",
    "jest": "27.0.4",
    "jest-junit": "12.2.0",
    "jest-sonar-reporter": "2.0.0",
    "json-loader": "0.5.7",
    "lighthouse": "8.0.0",
    "lint-staged": "11.0.0",
    "merge-jsons-webpack-plugin": "1.0.21",
    "mini-css-extract-plugin": "1.6.0",
    "postcss-loader": "6.1.0",
    "prettier": "2.3.1",
    "prettier-plugin-java": "1.2.0",
    "prettier-plugin-packagejson": "2.2.11",
    "puppeteer": "10.0.0",
    "react-infinite-scroller": "1.2.4",
    "redux-mock-store": "1.5.4",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "sass": "1.35.1",
    "sass-loader": "12.1.0",
    "simple-progress-webpack-plugin": "2.0.0",
    "sinon": "11.1.1",
    "source-map-loader": "3.0.0",
    "sourcemap-istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "0.2.0",
    "stripcomment-loader": "0.1.0",
    "style-loader": "2.0.0",
    "swagger-ui-dist": "3.50.0",
    "terser-webpack-plugin": "5.1.3",
    "thread-loader": "3.0.4",
    "to-string-loader": "1.1.6",
    "ts-jest": "27.0.3",
    "ts-loader": "9.2.3",
    "typescript": "4.3.3",
    "wait-on": "5.3.0",
    "webpack": "5.39.0",
    "webpack-cli": "4.7.2",
    "webpack-dev-server": "3.11.2",
    "webpack-merge": "5.8.0",
    "webpack-notifier": "1.13.0",
    "workbox-webpack-plugin": "6.1.5"
  }
```

Please help!!!

Answer (score 0):

workbox-webpack-plugin need to be update to lastest version. Current 6.2.4